# Layout on Magento does not load

Tags: magento, layout

I am a newbie in Magento.
I have problem, my website using Magento. I do not know Why it does not load layout (it alway load default layout of Magento).
This is my module config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>    

    <modules>
        <Inkatia_Layoutviewer>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Inkatia_Layoutviewer>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
           <layoutviewer>
               <use>standard</use>
               <args>
                   <module>Inkatia_Layoutviewer</module>
                   <frontName>layoutviewer</frontName>
               </args>
           </layoutviewer>
        </routers>
        <layout>
              <updates>
                  <layoutviewer>
                    <file>inkatia_layoutviewer.xml</file>
                  </layoutviewer>
              </updates>

        </layout>
    </frontend>

    <global>
        <models>
            <layoutviewer>
                <class>Inkatia_Layoutviewer_Model</class>
            </layoutviewer>
            <core>
                <rewrite>
                    <layout_update>Inkatia_Layoutviewer_Model_Layout_Update</layout_update>
                </rewrite>
            </core>
        </models>
        <events>
            <controller_action_postdispatch>
                <observers>
                    <layoutviewer>
                        <type>singleton</type>                      
                        <class>Inkatia_Layoutviewer_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkForLayoutDisplayRequest</method>
                    </layoutviewer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch>
        </events>
    </global>

</config>
```

And this is layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <default>
            <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="inkatia_layoutviewer/simple_page.phtml" />
        </default>

    </layout>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `</xml>` from the end of your layout file. The `<?xml>` declaration does not need to be closed. Check `var/log/system.log` and `var/log/exception.log` for any other XML parsing errors. Other than that, everything looks like it should work.

Comment: Actually the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` is not even a tag it is called an **xml declaration**. Further reading http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd